# Pasar Array que está dentro de un JSON como parámetro a una función

Tags: javascript, json, jsonarray

¡Hola a todos!

Tengo el siguiente Array dentro de un archivo JSON independiente:

```
[
    ["Triangulo", "Cuadrado","Rojo", "Caramelo"], 
    ["Circulo", "Zeta","Casco", "Móvil"],
    ["Calcetines", "Cuadrado","Rectángulo", "Aro"]
]
```

Obtengo dicho JSON en mi archivo principal de JS con la siguiente función:

```
    let fetchQuestions = () => {
       
        fetch('./src/scenes/questions.json')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

   fetchQuestions();
```

Y lo que quiero lograr es poder elegir cualquier índice de dicho JSON para pasarlo como parámetro a una función.

Para que quede más claro, si dicho Array que está dentro del JSON lo tuviese en mi archivo principal JS, simplemente haría lo siguiente:

```
    let miArray = [
     ["a","b","c"],
     ["a1","b1","c1"]
    ];

funcionEjemplo(...miArray[0]);
```

En este caso estaría tomando como parámetro el primer índice del array (["a","b","c"]).

Y quiero poder hacer esto mismo pero con `fetchQuestions();`. Quiero extraer el valor que me otorga dicha función y poder asignar el índice del Array que yo quiera a `funcionEjemplo();`, tal como mostré en el ejemplo anterior.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te habrás dado cuenta, fetch devuelve una promesa, por lo que para poder trabajar con los resultados de la función `fetchQuestions()` tienes que trabajar con **async/await**. He cambiado la url para el fetch (aunque no pude encontrar alguna API que me devuelva array de arrays) pero en principio debería funcionarte para tu caso específico.

Dada la naturaleza de `await`, este debe incluirse en una función `async`, de ahí que la función `mainFn()` sea asíncrona. En dicha función *esperamos* a que `fetchQuestions()` nos traiga los datos, y una vez que ya los tenemos podemos pasar alguno de los resultados a la función `sampleFn()` que como observarás, es una función normal, dado que ya hemos *esperado* por los resultados previamente. Ya en `sampleFn()` puedes trabajar con el resultado como si fuera una variable que ya existía previamente en tu código.

```js
const fetchQuestions = async () => {
  return await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

const sampleFn = (array) => {
  console.log(array);
}

const mainFn = async () => {
  // Obtener todos los resultados
  const questions = await fetchQuestions();

  // Pasar solo uno de ellos
  sampleFn(questions[0]);
}

mainFn();
```

**Nota:** No hago uso del operador spread porque como ya te comenté, no encontré una API que me devolviera array de arrays, lo que devuelve es una array de objetos, pero sin problemas debería funcionar con las modificaciones que harás para tu caso.